# Geoserver WPS with local shape

Tags: geoserver, wps

I'm trying to apply WPS for local shapefile.  Is it possible to process local shapefile directly as a input data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to use a shapefile as-is.

If the file is local to GeoServer (you tagged it, I assume that's what you are using), you can try to use a "file:///path/to/zipped/shapefile.zip" reference.

If the file is remote, you will have to zip it and add it to the request as a base64 encoded payload, or reference to it via HTTP (if you can zip it, and make it available on a web server that GeoServer can download from).

Comment: actually "local" means remote to geoserver. I'm trying to process local shape using remote geoserver.

Comment: Thanks, Andrea! it would be great if you can give me some hint to reference  remote shape zip via HTTP.